# Will removing an unused web service method break a SOAP client?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a **SOAP** web service which exposes two methods, `A` and `B`. The service is consumed by a Java **SOAP** client which invokes method `B`, but method `A` is not used anywhere.

I would like to remove method `A` entirely, can I safely do this without any impact on the client consuming the service?

> I know the WSDL will change, but I don't know what effect the client having a reference to a method which no longer exists will have if the client is not currently invoking `A`.

This is all predicated on the requirement that no changes be made to the Java client.

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally you should communicate the removal of method 'A' to the consumers. Technically there should not be any problem if 'A' is never called.

Comment: The removal of `A` has been communicated to the consumers, however they do not have the resources to update their client if any changes necessitate it so we are attempting to avoid that outcome. The obvious option is to strip `A` down to a dummy function, but I'd like to understand the effects of changing a WSDL more fully.

Comment: I meant there should not be any problem if 'A is removed from WSDL on server side, as long as is it never called by consumers. You can quickly test it with SOAPUI, by import full version of WSDL into SOAPUI and call 'B' against server that has 'A removed.

Answer (score 0):

If the call is never performed, the client won't fail, do it.
If the service is consumed by many clients, all of them should stop using it.